# Law of Demeter broken in the following AngularJS example?

Tags: angularjs, oop

How is the Law of Demeter broken in the following AngularJS example found in the Angular Docs:

```
myModule.factory('greeter', function($window) {
  return {
    greet: function(text) {
      $window.alert(text);
   }
 };
});
var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myModule']);
var greeter = injector.get('greeter');
```

I'm having trouble seeing how this is so.  Is it because the injector code is "reaching through" myModule to find the greeter service?  I'm new to angular, so I don't have a good understanding of angular internals yet.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: What led you to believe that the Law of Demeter is being broken in the first place?

Comment: The docs say so.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: This question might be better asked at programmers.stackexchange.com